# Triangles using 3 parallel lines

Tags: geometry

Three parallel lines L1
, L2
and L3
 are such that L1
 is 1 cm above L2
 and
L3
 is 2 cm below L2
. A right isosceles triangle has one of its vertices on each
line. What is the sum, in cm2
, of all possible values for the area of this triangle?

I tried using Coordinate geometry, the first, second and third lines were

$y=0$, $y=2$,   $y=3$ and the points where $(a,0)$, $(b,2)$, and $(c,3)$

Since it had to be isosceles, the distance between $(a,0)$ and $(b,2)$ must be equal to that of $(b,2)$ and $(c,3)$, the lines also connecting them must be perpendicular, i got 2 equations

$c^2-2bc = a^2-2ab +3$ (from the equal lengths)

$-b^2-ac+ab+bc=-2$ (from the slopes).

I cant seem to make use of them

Answer (score 1):

These are the possible triangles, depending on which line the right angle lies on:

[image]

The left triangle has leg length $\sqrt5$, the middle one $\sqrt{13}$ and the right one $\sqrt{10}$. Thus the sum of possible areas is $\frac12(5+13+10)=14$ square centimetres.